# Spring Boot Application - Maven Issue

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

i was developing one applications a while ago, and after long brake i've reopened it and try to change something and build application.

Now when i'm trying to build applicaton i have an issue with Maven

Could you please take a look in the ERROR and support me, what should i change/add?

I see this issue for the first time, and really no idea what is wrong, especially that one month ago it works fine.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.641 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-04T09:02:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/464M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project myapplication: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130\surefirebooter5461745518324810198.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130 2019-03-04T09-02-23_668-jvmRun1 surefire5550337711472069686tmp surefire_01955205028093789027tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130\surefirebooter5461745518324810198.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130 2019-03-04T09-02-23_668-jvmRun1 surefire5550337711472069686tmp surefire_01955205028093789027tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
...
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project myapplication: There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130\surefirebooter5461745518324810198.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130 2019-03-04T09-02-23_668-jvmRun1 surefire5550337711472069686tmp surefire_01955205028093789027tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130\surefirebooter5461745518324810198.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire3153501061038019130 2019-03-04T09-02-23_668-jvmRun1 surefire5550337711472069686tmp surefire_01955205028093789027tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    ....
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There are test failures.
```

TEST IS:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project application: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241\surefirebooter706544173501739081.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241 2019-03-04T09-28-58_374-jvmRun1 surefire700658503828727378tmp surefire_09037920200833720438tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241\surefirebooter706544173501739081.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241 2019-03-04T09-28-58_374-jvmRun1 surefire700658503828727378tmp surefire_09037920200833720438tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
...
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project application: There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241\surefirebooter706544173501739081.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241 2019-03-04T09-28-58_374-jvmRun1 surefire700658503828727378tmp surefire_09037920200833720438tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241\surefirebooter706544173501739081.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241 2019-03-04T09-28-58_374-jvmRun1 surefire700658503828727378tmp surefire_09037920200833720438tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241\surefirebooter706544173501739081.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241 2019-03-04T09-28-58_374-jvmRun1 surefire700658503828727378tmp surefire_09037920200833720438tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241\surefirebooter706544173501739081.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire1234626952071494241 2019-03-04T09-28-58_374-jvmRun1 surefire700658503828727378tmp surefire_09037920200833720438tmp"
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
```

Inside log file i see

```
# Created on 2019-03-04T09:29:00.628
Killing self fork JVM. Maven process died.
```

Comment: "There are test failures" So run the tests and see. We can't help you beyond that, given this little information.

Comment: The following message is also relevant : "refer to D:\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\JAVA\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results"

Comment: There are test failures. - fix tests or remove them.

Comment: mvn whatever -DskipTests

Comment: How can i skip test in Intellij? I know that i can invoke commant in cmd, but until now it worked in Intellij without any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From terminal:**

Add `-DskipTests` to `mvn` command as a workaround. For instance:

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

This builds the package fine.

**From IntelliJ, like you mentioned, you can do the following:**

View > Tool Windows > Maven Projects click on the button called Skip Tests Mode. Essentially it is taking the test phase out of the lifecycle when you say run package.

I hope it helps for the time being until an unless the issue with test cases are solved.

Comment: I think this is bad advice. Just skipping failing tests is asking for trouble. There's surely a reason why a test fails.